# Multiple Owners in Opportunity Record

Tags: record-owner

I have multiple Owners for my Opportunity Record. One is the Default Owner (Mostly Record Creator) and Second is a Lookup to Users "Secondary Owner". Now my requirement is I need to give all the access of my default owner to the Secondary Owner.

How can I achieve this?

Nirav

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For multiple "owners", add the additional users as Team Members on the opportunity. This will grant them read (and optionally, edit) permissions. However, unlike the primary owner, they will be unable to delete the opportunity, and there is no direct way to give them this permission without giving them the permission to delete any opportunity in the system, which is presumably not what you want to do. You can read more about this in [Guidelines for Using Opportunity Teams](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=salesteam_def.htm&type=5).

Comment: Thnks, I will go with Opportunity Team, just thinking that I will call a flow when user selects the secondary owner. Can you please let me know your thoughts on this idea?? Should I go ahead with this??

Comment: @NiravShah Yes, that should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Apex Sharing here. You will have to write a trigger on Opportunity with after insert and after update events.
And share the records with the secondary owners. You can go through [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_bulk_sharing_creating_with_apex.htm) salesforce document to understand how to share a record using apex.

Note:

- Make sure that the secondary owner has all the necessary permissions at the profile level.
- Make sure to delete the share records of old owner when the lookup value is changed i.e. old secondary owner's share records should be deleted once its value is changed.

Below trigger should fulfill your requirement.

```
trigger OpportunityTrigger on Opportunity (after insert,after update) {
    List<OpportunityShare> oppShareToInsert = new List<OpportunityShare>();
    Set<Id> userIds = new Set<Id>();
    List<OpportunityShare> oppShareToDelete = new List<OpportunityShare>();
    if((Trigger.IsInsert || Trigger.IsUpdate) && Trigger.IsAfter){
        for(Opportunity opp : Trigger.New){
            if(Trigger.oldMap==null || opp.Secondary_Owner__c != Trigger.oldMap.get(opp.Id).Secondary_Owner__c){
                OpportunityShare opShare = new OpportunityShare();
                opShare.UserOrGroupId = opp.Secondary_Owner__c; 
                opShare.OpportunityAccessLevel = 'Edit'; //Any access level you wish to assign
                opShare.OpportunityID = oppId;
                oppShareToInsert.add(opShare);

                if(Trigger.oldMap!=null && opp.Secondary_Owner__c != Trigger.oldMap.get(opp.Id).Secondary_Owner__c){
                    userIds.add(Trigger.oldMap.get(opp.Id).Secondary_Owner__c);
                }
            } 
        }
        if(!userIds.isEmpty()){
            delete [select id from OpportunityShare where OpportunityID IN : Trigger.new and UserOrGroupId IN: userIds];
        }
        if(!oppShareToInsert.isEmpty()){
            insert oppShareToInsert;
        }
    }
}
```